# Localizar endereços mais próximos no Google Maps

Tags: html5, google-maps

Tenho mais de 2000 mil registros em uma base de dados com endereço e CEP, e quero  localizar os estabelecimentos mais próximos do meu CEP utilizando o API do Google Maps.

[Exemplo do que preciso](http://clareslab.com.br/learn/cep/).

Mas no meu caso quero localizar alguns dos registros na base de dados mais próximo do CEP digitado.

Comment: Já tem bastante luz aqui no site (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps), o ideal é você pesquisar antes de perguntar (confira o mini guia [ask]). E bem vindo ao site :)

Comment: Boa tarde, eu não entendi é localizar endereço ou estabelecimentos? O titulo diz uma coisa e a pergunta outra.

Comment: bigown, você conseguiu fazer essa funcionalidade do jeito que você perguntou aqui? Como você fez?

Answer (score 3):

Uma solução é consultar a API com cada CEP gravado no banco (*destinations*), com o CEP informado pelo cliente (*origins*), gravar em uma lista e ordenar pelo menor valor da distância.

Para limitar a consulta, pode-se utilizar como parâmetro a cidade, buscando assim apenas os CEP (do banco) da cidade informada pelo cliente.

**Exemplo:** http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=99064090&destinations=saopaulo&mode=driving&language=pt-BR&sensor=false

---

Acredito ainda que [este tutorial](http://cbsa.com.br/post/distancia-entre-cidades---google-maps-javascript-api-v3.aspx) possa te ajudar.